# App hangs when i reach the last sound clip in ios5

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4

I have a app with images and once the user presses the image a sound clip will be played.  Once i reach the last image (25), which does not have a sound clip, if i press that the app gets closed automatically how can i prevent this.

For example i need to play C01.mp3 once the user Click 01.Png ( Note all my images are also kept in a image array )  Basically I have 25.png this is just a advertisement to my site so it would not have a sound clip but once i click that image the applicaiton gets close automatically. Need help to sort this out.

```
//

#import "SoundsGenerator.h"


@implementation SoundsGenerator

- (id) init
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle;
    mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle ();

    soundObjects=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *soundNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"c1",
                                @"c2", 
                                @"c3", 
                                @"c4", 
                                @"c5", 
                                @"c6", 
                                @"c7", 
                                @"c8", 
                                @"c9", 
                                @"c10", 
                                @"c11", 
                                @"c12", 
                                @"c13", 
                                @"c14", 
                                @"c15", 
                                @"c16", 
                                @"c17", 
                                @"c18", 
                                @"c19", 
                                @"c20", 
                                @"c21", 
                                @"c22", 
                                @"c23", 
                                @"c24",nil];    

    for(NSString *soundName in soundNames)
    {
        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
        soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (__bridge CFStringRef)soundName, CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);

        SystemSoundID soundFileObject;
        // Create a system sound object representing the sound file
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef, &soundFileObject);

        SoundObject *objSound=[[SoundObject alloc] init];
        objSound.soundFileObject=soundFileObject;
        objSound.soundFileURLRef=soundFileURLRef;
        [soundObjects addObject:objSound];
    }

    return self;
}

// Respond to a tap on the System Sound button
- (void) playSound:(int)index 
{
    SoundObject *soundObject=[soundObjects objectAtIndex:index];
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound ((SystemSoundID)soundObject.soundFileObject);
}


@end
```

Comment: where does the program crash exactly? what is the console message?

Comment: You only have *24* sound names, do you mean it crashes on the 24th?  Or that iterates past the 24th and crashes when it his the sentinel?

Comment: If you are trying to play a sound that isn't there (accessing an index past the bounds of your soundObjects), then you will crash.

Comment: Yes so how can I avoid that I need to check if the image is img1.png then it should play c01.mp3 actually the last image is just a add to my other apps so there won't be any sound file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
for(NSString *soundName in soundNames)
{
```

with

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < soundNames.count-1 ; i++)
{
   NSString *soundName = [soundNames objectAtIndex:i];
   //rest of the code same
```

**This will run the loop till 23 indexes of your 24 indexes array..**